# Combining 3 output from 3 queries in mysql and do some calculations

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

Table 1 - `mdl_question_attempts`

```
id      questionid               rightanswer                responsesummary

1       1                        A                          A

2       1                        A                          B

3       1                        A                          A

4       1                        A                          B

5       2                        A                          A

6       1                        A                          A

7       2                        D                          E

8       2                        D                          D

9       2                        D                          E

10      3                        F                          F

11      3                        F                          G
```

Table 2 - `mdl_question_attempt_steps`

```
id         questionattemptid                            userid

5          1                                            1

6          2                                            1

7          3                                            2

8          4                                            1

9          5                                            2

10         6                                            1

11         7                                            1

12         8                                            1

13         9                                            1

14         10                                           1

15         11                                           1
```

Table 1 - `mdl_question_attempts`, primary key – `id` field is related with

Table 2 - `mdl_question_attempt_steps` , foreign key – `questionattemptid`

Table 1 is about users answers for certain questions.

`rightanswer` - is the correct answer for a particular question and `responsesummary` is the answer given by user for that question.  “questionid” represent the question no.  Sometimes same user tried one question several times and their answer in each attempts shows in table 1.

For each question  “userid” or user can be found from Table 2

```
Eg: 1st row in table1 done by userid =1
```

So my question is I want to find percentage or ratio of times a learner(one user-eg:userid =1)  answers the same question twice wrong, based on the number of times a learner answered a question twice?

Highlighted ones in the table 1 shows the userid=1  related data

User1  answered question 1 – 4 times and it is 2 times wrong

User1  answered question 2 – 3 times and it is 2 times wrong

Question 3 is answered 2 times and only 1 time wrong. So I want same question twice wrong. Therefore

Question 3 is not considered

```
questionid       wrong count



1                    2/4

2                    2/3
```

So my final output for the `userid=1` is

```
=((2/4)+(2/3))/2

=0.583
```

=summation of wrong count divided by average or that is 2 times (only 2 questioned answerd) If 3 question answered summation should be divided by 3.

I wrote following three codes and I can get the output separately. But I want to get this in one query

```
            function quiztwicewrong()

            {

            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","", "moodle");

            // Check connection

            if (mysqli_connect_errno())

            {

                            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

            }

            //quiz twice wrong
```

Query 1

```
            $resultq = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT  mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer as rightanswer,count(mdl_question_attempts.questionid) as questionid1 FROM mdl_question_attempts,mdl_question_attempt_steps WHERE  mdl_question_attempt_steps.questionattemptid=mdl_question_attempts.id and mdl_question_attempt_steps.userid='1'  and mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer<>mdl_question_attempts.responsesummary GROUP BY mdl_question_attempts.questionid HAVING questionid1>1 ") or die("Error: ".     mysqli_error($con));

            while($rowq= mysqli_fetch_array( $resultq))

            {

                            echo $rowq['questionid1']."-".$rowq['rightanswer']."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";

            }
```

Query 2

```
            $resultqall = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT  mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer as rightanswer,count(mdl_question_attempts.questionid) as questionid1 FROM mdl_question_attempts,mdl_question_attempt_steps WHERE  mdl_question_attempt_steps.questionattemptid=mdl_question_attempts.id and mdl_question_attempt_steps.userid='1'  GROUP BY mdl_question_attempts.questionid HAVING questionid1>1") or die("Error: ".     mysqli_error($con));

            while($rowqall= mysqli_fetch_array( $resultqall))

            {

                            echo $rowqall['questionid1']."-".$rowqall['rightanswer']."<br>"."<br>"."<br>";

            }



                            //query 3            

            $resultqdup = mysqli_query ($con,"SELECT count(*) as duplicate FROM

                                            (select mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer as  ightanswer from mdl_question_attempts,mdl_question_attempt_steps WHERE  mdl_question_attempt_steps.questionattemptid=mdl_question_attempts.id and mdl_question_attempt_steps.userid='1'  and mdl_question_attempts.rightanswer<>mdl_question_attempts.responsesummary GROUP BY mdl_question_attempts.questionid HAVING COUNT(mdl_question_attempts.questionid)>1) as questionid1 ") or die("Error: ".     mysqli_error($con));

            while($rowqdup= mysqli_fetch_array( $resultqdup))

            {

                            echo $rowqdup['duplicate'];

            }



            mysqli_close($con);

          }

          return quiztwicewrong();
```

Outputs from the 3 queries are

query 1- ouput

```
2-A

2-D
```

query 2- ouput

```
4-A

3-D

2-F   (I don’t want this part-this comes for the 3rd question, but  I want only the output related to query 1- ouput,only answer more than 1 time wromg)
```

query 3- ouput

2

So I want to combine 3 output and need to calculate and get the value

```
=((2/4)+(2/3))/2

=0.583
```

Please help me to do this by editing my code or any suggestion please?

Comment: Add a SQLFiddle.com example to avoid all table confusions, then format your code properly and remove unwanted sections of code, with such formatting and such a huge question very few will venture out to answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much. I was able to solved the problem with the help of my friend from another forum. If you think that this solution is necessary for any one, I posted that solution

```
SELECT ROUND(SUM(incorrect/answered)/COUNT(*), 3) as result
FROM
(
SELECT qa.questionid, 
SUM(IF(qa.rightanswer <> qa.responsesummary, 1, 0)) as incorrect ,
COUNT(*) as answered
FROM mdl_question_attempts qa
    INNER JOIN mdl_question_attempt_steps qas
    ON qa.id = qas.questionattemptid
WHERE qas.userid = $user
GROUP BY qa.questionid
HAVING incorrect > 1
) as totals
```